# Как выбрать из соединения таблиц уникальные значения?

Tags: sql

Путем соединения таблиц HR.EMPLOYEES, HR.DEPARTMENTS и HR.LOCATIONS посчитать среднюю зарплату сотрудников, которые работают в разных странах.
Попробовал сделать так:

```
select e.department_id, avg(salary) as avg_salary from hr.employees e
join hr.departments j on (e.department_id = j.department_id)
join hr.locations l on (j.location_id = l.location_id)
having unique(l.country_id)
```

Но это не сработало, как можно выбрать только разные страны?
Вот примеры таблиц:
hr.employees:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90
```

hr.departments:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
10              Administration  200           1700
```

hr.locations:

```
LOCATION_ID STREET_ADDRESS        POSTAL_CODE   CITY    STATE_PROVINCE  COUNTRY_ID
1000        1297 Via Cola di Rie    00989       Roma      -               IT
```

UPD:
Попробовал так:

```
select e.department_id, avg(salary) as avg_salary, l.country_id from hr.employees e, hr.locations l
join hr.departments j on (e.department_id = j.department_id)
join hr.locations l on (j.location_id = l.location_id)
group by l.country_id
```

Выводит ошибку: `"E"."DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 1):

Что насчёт `group by`? Вам же надо сгруппировать результат по странам. Ну и группируйте. id департамента вам не нужен, только `country_id` и `avg(salary)`.

Comment: добавил исправленную версию, все равно не работает

Comment: @YaroslavRume >id департамента вам не нужен

Comment: Да я убрал это, сделал group by e.salary, l.country_id, все равно неудачно

Comment: @YaroslavRume >надо сгруппировать результат по странам Зачем вы группируете по зарплате?

Comment: Ой, точно, но он все равно ругается на "E"."DEPARTMENT_ID": invalid identifier, не могу найти ошибку

Comment: @YaroslavRume что у вас в from? Там должен быть `from hr.employees e`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141231/discussion-between---and-yaroslav-rume).